# Java check username and password for matching(from xml file)

Tags: java, xml

```
@XmlElement(name = "Emp", type = UserBean.class)
        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Emps")
        private List<UserBean> users;       

 if (users.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.getUsername().equals(userBean.getUsername()))
                    && users.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.getPassowrd().equals(userBean.getPassowrd()))) {
                login=true;
    }
```

This function checks whether a password and name exist in a container. I fill the container from xml file. However, that only check that items are existing, not the matching.

xml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Department>
        <Emps>
            <Emp>
                <username>Name</username>
                <password>name</password>
            </Emp>
            <Emp>
                <username>Name2</username>
                <password>name2</password>
            </Emp>

    </Emps>
</Department>
```

So I can enter username **Name** and the password **name2** and login still will be true. Are they any ways to set login to true only if username and password are matching?

Comment: [Don't use `String`s for passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just merge the conditions into a single predicate:

```
if (users.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.getUsername().equals(userBean.getUsername())
        && x.getPassowrd().equals(userBean.getPassowrd())))
```